# To find product $\cos{\theta}\cos{2\theta}\cos{3\theta}...\cos{999\theta}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

How to find out value of product

$$\cos{\theta}\cos{2\theta}\cos{3\theta}...\cos{999\theta}$$
where

$\theta=\frac{2\pi}{1999}$

i tried to multiply and divide by sin\theta to convert to sin2A, but couldnot do it. i would like to know many methods, if possible, to do this question

thanks

Comment: Well, whatever it is, it must be EXTREMELY close to zero.

Comment: @Rohan How do you find duplicates so fast?

Comment: @S.C.B Fast?? I found it 14 minutes after the OP posted the question. Just search the site, sir.

Comment: @Rohan I couldn't find it when I searched the site.

Comment: @S.C.B Sir, put this in the search box: `Find the value of $\cos x \cos 2x `

Comment: @Rohan How do you know to put that? I put in `$\cos{\theta}\cos{2\theta}\cos{3\theta}...\cos{999\theta}$`

Comment: @dxiv odd angles are left out

Comment: @TaylorTed I spoke too hastily, thanks for the correction.